# Column list specification in INSERT OVERWRITE statement

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While trying to OVERWRITE the Hive table with specific columns from Spark(Pyspark) using a dataframe getting the below error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'col1' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 36)\n\n== SQL ==\ninsert OVERWRITE table DB.TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM dataframe\n------------------------------------^^^\n"
```

Based on the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9481 looks like **column-list** is still not supported in **INSERT OVERWRITE**, so on trying to run without the overwrite keyword still gives me the same error.

```
sparkSession.sql("insert into table DB.TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM dataframe")
```

> Note: The above works fine when the specific column-list is not
>   specified, and the columns between the tables match.

But on trying the same via *`Hive Terminal`* goes through fine.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE DB.TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) select Col1, Col2, Col3 from DB.TableName2;
```

Should any property or configuration be set or passed through the `Spark-Submit`

Please do let me know if you need more data or information..

Comment: But in hive you are specifying  `partition(Col1)`?

Comment: @karma4917 corrected the query..:) the reason was actually I would like to have the Hive table partitioned, hence had tried the query with both partitioned and un-partitioned.

Comment: @karma4917 any specific reason the Pyspark is throwing error while specifying the columns which works in the Hive Terminal ?

Comment: Can you try defining `sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)` and try to use, `sqlContext.sql('''insert into table DB.TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3) select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM dataframe''')` (Note to use three ''' '''). Ah, now I see it did you write `dataframe` first?

Comment: @karma4917 had tried the HiveContext too, though no luck with that too. And as per the  [SPARK-20845](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20845) looks like its a work in progress. And for the question about `dataframe` yes it contains data.